# Django next redirect with default view

Tags: django, authentication, redirect

I'm trying to enter the page while I'm not logged in and app redirect me to login page and getting the next parameter is working (ex.

`localhost:8000/login/?next=/blog/add/`

but when I enter login and password and click login button it redirect me to home page, not that one that is in the next parameter

`localhost:8000, not localhost:8000/blog/add/`

I'm using default django login view so it is possible to do this without changing anything in login view?

Everything is default by django, I added only next parameter while redirecting to login page (with using @login_required(login_url='login')), I heard that Django has built in feature for redirecting after login with next parameter and nothing more is required?

urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$',
        django.contrib.auth.views.login,
        {
            'template_name': 'user/login.html',
            'authentication_form': user.forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Logowanie',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        },
        name='login'),
```

login.html

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4>Uzyj konta LDAP zeby sie zalogowac</h4>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.username }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        {{ form.password }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-pb" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% if form.errors %}
                <p class="validation-summary-errors">Please enter a correct user name and password.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
```

Comment: I have to show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have hardcoded the `next` variable as `/` in your template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
```

You should change it to use `{{ next }}`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

Comment: Problem solved. That was so bad i didn't think about it... thanks